# Empty params object in express.js middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

```
const app = express();
var router = require('express').Router({mergeParams: true});
const payloadMiddleware = (req, resp, next) => {
  console.log('A:',req.params);
  const {params, query} = req;
  const payload = req.body;
  req.my_params = { params, query, payload };
  next();
};

router.use(payloadMiddleware);

router.get('/inventory/:itemID/price', async function GetPrice(req, res, next) {
  console.log('B', req.my_params);
  console.log('C', req.params);
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', router);
server = app.listen(port);
```

`GET /inventory/abc/price?a=1&b=2` yields

```
A: {} # unclear why this is empty
B: { params: {},
     query: { a: '1', b: '2' },
     payload: {} } 
C: {itemID: 'abc'}
```

So I'm confused: I expect my middleware to find `params` in `req`, construct the new object, and assign it to `req` as `my_params`, then pass that to the inventory handler. And this is partially happening, in that the querystring is being parsed and then assigned in my middleware. Why is `req.params === {}` in my middleware function, but `req.params = {itemID: 'abc'}`in the GET handler itself?

There are no other routes with the same pattern, no other middleware...

Also no change is observed when I remove the options object from the second line, i.e. `var router = require('express').Router();`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`payloadMiddleware` is a generic middleware that isn't declared for any specific URL pattern containing parameters (it matches *any* request).

Express also doesn't know that requests passed to the middleware will eventually end up in the handler for `/inventory/:itemID/price`.

If you want the middleware to receive the parameters, you have to specifically use it against routes that match a pattern:

```
app.use('/inventory/:itemID/price', payloadMiddleware);
```

Or as part of the route handler:

```
router.get('/inventory/:itemID/price', payloadMiddleware, async function ...);
```

Comment: I had based this on my understanding of the default mount point from the express docs: "Uses the specified middleware function or functions, with optional mount path path, that defaults to “/”." So the params will only be set if the middleware is specifically `use`d on a given path? There is no way to specify that I want that middleware to be used and have the path params for EVERY request?

Comment: @Ben no, that's not possible, mainly because a middleware, when used standalone, is oblivious of any other middleware or route handlers. Even Express won't know beforehand if a request will end up matching a particular parameterized route pattern, so it can't generate `req.params` beforehand (also for the simple reason that you may have numerous parameterized routes, so without knowing where a request will end up, it won't know which route parameters to parse against).